# Comparing linear sets of data

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, linear-model

I'm trying to validate the use of different sample tubes in a pharma environment. We have an established method with a linear calibration curve and QCs at three concentrations within the curve range. To compare the different tubes we made five replicates of each QC concentration in each type of tube so 45 samples in total. In the data below Tube 1 is used in the validated method, Tubes 2 and 3 are the new tubes we are testing. So we would like to see no change with respect to Tube 1.

Just performing linear fits on the three sets of data in r was enough to convince me that there is no adsorption of the drug to the container walls, but of course my intuition isn't enough to validate a method. I need a p value (or some measure of significance), and the PI specifically asked for a two way ANOVA. Is that really the best way to handle this sort of data, and if so can you give some tips to get it going in R? I tried but failed quickly. I'm open to excel and other programs as well if it is easier for you.

Data:

```
Specified Conc.,Tube 1,Tube 2,Tube 3
0.1,0.104,0.102,0.103
0.1,0.102,0.101,0.105
0.1,0.103,0.104,0.102
0.1,0.105,0.105,0.100
0.1,0.104,0.103,0.103
8,7.84,8.08,7.64
8,8.20,8.20,8.12
8,7.92,7.92,7.92
8,8.12,8.08,8.08
8,8.04,7.92,8.08
28,29.1,28.1,28.6
28,28.3,28.3,28.3
28,28.2,28.5,28.1
28,28.3,28.3,28.6
28,28.1,28.6,28.4
```

Comment: What is the hypothesis to which this p-value is supposed to apply?  Exactly how is "no adsorption of the drug to the container walls" to be expressed in terms of the data?

Comment: The null hypothesis would be no change, which is what we are wanting, so I would expect a high p-value.

Comment: Could you please clarify what "no change" might mean?  In what quantity, with respect to what other quantity?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I put that in the initial post. Tube 1 is used in the validated method, Tubes 2 and 3 are the new tubes we are testing. So we would like to see no change  with respect to Tube 1.

Comment: If you only had one concentration here I would point you to Bland and Altman plots which have their own tag here [tag:bland-altman-plot] Some variation might work.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be much more comfortable with a single concentration as well but unfortunately adsorption could be concentration dependent so we need a range.

Comment: Please include this additional information by editing your post.